# if else does not return anything in swift3

Tags: swift, alamofire

I have a function in swift3 that gets the approved variable and checks if it is true. If it is true then it will show an alert, but if it is not true, then nothing happens when it should be showing an alert that the approval was denied.  It won't even print anything when I try to replace the alert with a simple print()

What could be the issue?

```
@IBAction func approveuser(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    theplace = place //Saving variable.


    DispatchQueue.main.async {

        if(self.place == ""){
            self.place = self.pickerData[0]
        }

        //BEGIN CHECK.
        Alamofire.request("https://example.com/api.php?appvar=\(appvar)&requested=\(self.place)").responseJSON{ (response) -> Void in

            if let JSON = response.result.value{
                let json = JSON as! NSDictionary
                Approved = json["Approved"] as! String
                let version = json["version"] as! String

                if(version != AppVersion){
                    self.showalert("Update Required", message: "A new version is available. Please update!", confirm: "Okay")
                    return
                }

                if(Approved == "true"){
                    theurl = json["URL"] as! String //Give the URL.
                    self.showalert("Approved!", message: "Approved", confirm: "Okay")
                }else{
                    self.showalert("Denied!", message: "Denied", confirm: "Okay")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does the code execute pass the "if let" statement ? Have you tried adding breakpoints ?

Comment: Yes, it will execute past that. It doesn't seem to want to handle anything after the }else{. I tried making some breakpoints as well to test with those but they didn't help me pinpoint the problem

Comment: So the if you put the breakpoint in "else" it doesn't fire up ?

Comment: No, it doesn't, it still does nothing when putting it in the line with  }else{

Comment: @Matt Try `print(Approved)` before this line: `if(Approved == "true"){` what's the output?

Comment: @SamM That is doing nothing as well. Even trying `print("Test")` before the `if(Approved == "true"){` does nothing.

Comment: it probably doesn't go past "if let JSON = response.result.value"

Comment: Or it returns after  "if(version != AppVersion)"

Comment: @Matt Well then the program is not reaching there. Try `print("test1")` before `if(version != AppVersion){` and try ``print("test2")` inside that if statement before `return`

Comment: Add a breakpoint and do steps

Comment: @SamM Strangely even before the app version check test1 does not print. I also did test2 inside the statement but that doesn't work either and I don't think it should since version IS equal to AppVersion

Comment: @Matt Then It's definitely not going past the if-let statement. I think you're not getting a response. `print(response.result.value)` before `if let JSON = response.result.value{`, you'll most likely see `nil` as the output.

Comment: @SamM Yes, printing that is showing nil, but I can't think of why it still gives the "Approved" alert and sets `theurl` variable if that's the case

Comment: @Matt Do you change any part of the url in your request when testing the "Approved" situation ? or any of the variables that are in that url? like `appvar` and `self.place` ?

Comment: @SamM self.place is a UIPickerView value that changes when a user chooses something else in the picker view but other than that that's it. The URL doesn't change

Answer (score -1):

after this line

```
Approved = json["Approved"] as! String
```

print Approved

```
print(Approved)
```

make sure it prints either true or false
make sure it does not print optional(true) nor optional(false)

json response after upgrading to Swift 3 returns many optional values, even though you didn't change anything in your code after upgrading from Swift 2

Comment: If it prints optional true/false, it would still work. When comparing, it will compare the actual string, not "Optional(String)", thats just what the compiler does to show you. Also, regardless, even if this result was nil, the else would print.